# Use different google account for in app purchases?

Tags: google, in-app-purchase

so I'm signed into an app (pokemon go) with my primary google account. However I have credit on my secondary account that I want to use to buy some in app purchases. It won't let me do this and only gives me options to pay using the first account, this makes sense but its quite annoying. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just uninstalled the app, logged into my second account on my pc on the play store website. Then I installed it from the website using the seconds account. After that I logged into the pokemon app using my first google account then i was able to spend the credit from my second account.

Comment: The best solution ever!
Thanks a lot you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged into an account, you have to use that account. It is the way it "remembers" or saves progress. What you could do if you had say, 20 bucks on your other account. Send gift credits to the account you want to use. I think the increments are in 5 only though so it may hinder you from adding more. I hope this helps.